# I would like to convert the date to the Brazilian standard in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm doing some python code in Jupyter.
When I import my spreadsheet using Pandas, the date column automatically appears in **yyyy/mm/dd** format and I would like it to be in **dd/mm/yyyy** (that is the brazilian standart) as it is in my original spreadsheet because when I insert that column into a variable , it comes with this information + 00:00:00.

As I'm creating for automation in sending messages via Whatsapp, I won't be able to change line by line before sending the message.

Comment: Please provide an example of the data and the explicit expected output

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas date/time function, such as [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to do the conversion for you and [`dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to format as text.

Here is an example:

```
# dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'date_before': ['2021/01/01', '2021/01/02', '2021/01/03', '2021/01/04',
       '2021/01/05']})
# conversion
df['date_after'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_before']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

output:

```
  date_before  date_after
0  2021-01-01  01/01/2021
1  2021-01-02  02/01/2021
2  2021-01-03  03/01/2021
3  2021-01-04  04/01/2021
4  2021-01-05  05/01/2021
```

*NB. if you want to overwrite the column, just assign back to the same name*

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```